How can I set an inserted float object to go over the bottom of the page?
How can I set an inserted float object to go over the bottom of the page? For example, if I insert an image, it is not a problem that it goes over the left or right margin, but if it is in a float object, I cannot move it over the bottom of the page, it goes directly to the new page. Is it because when I insert the image via a float object, the image still has a caption and therefore goes to the new page?
What I mean with a inserted float object:


One way is to add negative space at the bottom of the float, causing it to overlap the bottom of the page or whatever else winds up below the float.  There is also a command which will add extra space at the bottom of a page, but I don't remember how to spell it.

Thank you after 30 days I was now able to fix it .. You need to add in the float object, but after the caption, with ctrl+L the command: "\vspace*{-1cm}", for me was important to add the vspace with the: "*".
(If -1cm isn´t enough, you have to increase the negative value e.g. to -3cm.)

BTW, I found the other command: \enlargethispage  (It was the "this" that threw me off.)

After 30 days I was now able to fix it O.O ... (With the help of John Kormylo).
You need to add in the float object, but after the caption, with ctrl+L the command: "\vspace*{-1cm}", for me was important to add the vspace with the: "*".
(If -1cm isn´t enough, you have to increase the negative value e.g. to -3cm.)
Example:

edit:
John  Kormylo showed another code, which also works very well, was for my important, when I used algorithms:
\enlargethispage{1cm}  (But for me it worked, when I puted it before the float-object, better to say outside the float object and before :).)
